# mysql SELECT * WHERE value = $row['item']

Tags: php, mysql

What's the correct way to code the following

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE value = $row['item']
```

`$row['item']` echos correctly, but does not seem to work in the mysql query. Been having this problem for a few days. I've tried `.$row['item'].` and a few other variations but I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM table WHERE value = {$row['item']}" work?

Comment: Can I *please* get an answer using placeholders? I am really tempted to *down-vote* all the replies with string interpolation (*with or without* `mysql_real_escape_string`). It is 2011. Please use modern accepted (everywhere *but* PHP it seems) constructs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better more appropriate approach is to use mysqli and prepared statements ie:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE value =?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$row['item']);  // I am assuming row['item'] is a string
$stmt->execute();
```

If you can't use mysqli or absolutely refuse to you can use this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE value = '".mysql_real_escape_string($row['item'])."'";
```

Comment: Please show example of a prepared statement first with the backwards approach second.

Comment: @pst: I hope this is more useful now ;)

Comment: @GWW: I cringe every time I see the second method, as it's vulnerable to SQL injection.  The ONLY way to do this is to use `?` placeholders and bind parameters.  With 11K rep you should know not to recommend the second option.

Comment: @Jim Garrison: I don't use the second method but I was just answering the users question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer sort of depends on what is held within the `$row['item']` variable. If it's a numeric value, then the query above should be fine. Since it's not working, I assume that the value of that variable is actually a string. In that case, you need to surround the value in quotes so that the database can correctly identify it as a string value (otherwise, it would just be gibberish "commands" that the database can't identify, causing the query to fail).

Regardless of the above, you shouldn't be directly inserting variables into a query under pretty much any circumstances. The reason is that it opens you up to SQL injection if you're not extremely careful. For example, if your `$row['item']` variable was wrapped in single quotes in the query, but *contained* a single quote in its value, then the database would interpret the quote within the variable as the ending quote for the entire parameter, and it would screw up the query. Worse still, a hacker could take advantage of this to end your query entirely, then add a second query of his own making onto it (or they could introduce a UNION query on the end of the original, etc.). At the very least, you should be running something like [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) on the variable before using it:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE value = " . 
        mysql_real_escape_string($row['item']);
```

The best way to get around this and secure your queries is to use prepared statements. These are queries that have placeholders in them instead of concatenated variables. You prepare the query with these placeholders, then you issue additional commands to the database to tell it what values to place in those placeholders. The database then takes care of the tricky issue of sanitizing these variables so that they don't cause any damage. You can use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for this:

```
try {
  $dbh = new PDO(DB_DSN, 
                 DB_USER, 
                 DB_PASS,
                 array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)
             );
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
  exit();
}

// create query with a named placeholder
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE value = :value";

try {
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

  // tell PDO to substitute the value in $row['item']
  // for the named parameter specified above.
  $stmt->bindValue(":value", $row['item']);

  // execute the query and load the results into an array
  $stmt->execute();
  $records = $stmt->fetchAll();

} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Query failed: " . $e->getMessage();
  exit();
}

foreach ($records as $record) {
  // use db records
}
```

Comment: Apparently I need to step my php knowledge up a touch.

Comment: @user895425 Don't feel too bad about it. SQL injection is an epidemic amongst PHP developers. Now that you know about prepared statements, however, you have no excuse for doing it wrong ever again. ;) If this answer solved your problem, please remember to mark it as accepted.

Comment: +1 Exactly the sort of answer I was hoping for from this question ^^

Comment: @pst Thank you. It was your comment on the question that led me to write it up, since there were already a number of answers when I got here.

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually recommend doing it is something like this:

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM table WHERE value = '%s'",
    mysql_real_escape_string($row['item']));
```

Comment: I don't. I recommend using placeholders. An example -- *or at least a mention of* -- such would be nice.

Comment: Depending on the application and the connection used, a placeholder approach may be out of place. While I agree, it would be better to use prepared statements, I don't think that answers the question at hand - it just shows an alternate (albiet better) method of executing statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
$item = mysql_real_escape_string($row['item']);
$mysqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE value = '" . $item . "'";
```

Comment: -1 Doesn't even use "escape_string" (although placeholders/prepared statements should be preferred instead)

Comment: Again - that doesn't solve the problem, as I see it - it just restates the problem a different way.

Answer (score -2):

you are missing single quotes

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE value = '{$row['item']}'
```

PHP example

Comment: if the other approaches don't work, this one isn't much better. It dereferences the array element correctly, but doesn't account for any possible quotes inside the element.

Comment: yes, but the question was about a poorly formatted sql query, the answer is the missing single quotes... so to make this right for you how about this:  $item = mysql_real_escape_string($row['item']);  SELECT * FROM table WHERE value = '{$item}'