# Why is it not saving on the database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have an input form for a sample php.

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>First Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Last Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Age:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="age" name="age" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Add Person!" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

and the insert.php goes like this

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
    $db = "phptest";    

    if(!$con)
    {
        die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db($db,$con);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO persons (FirstName,LastName,Age) VALUES ('$_POST[fname]','$_POST[lname]','$_POST[age]')";
    mysql_query($sql,$con);
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

It works fine for the first input. When I input another values and press the submit button, the data is not saving into the database. In the database, it only shows 1 row filled with my first input. What's the problem on the code for insert.php? Thanks.

Comment: Never feed $_POST data directly into a mysql query. Escape the input using mysql_real_escape_string first.

Comment: You'll need to santize your inputs in case you get Little Bobby Tables.

Comment: I see, that's the sample from w3school. I just copy it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please also do

```
echo mysql_error();
```

right after mysql_query() to know if something is wrong, although your query seems pretty fine.

Also, posting your table structure might help. *It might be that you forgot to have an id in your table that is set to primary_key and auto_increment*

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you're passing data into the query that has a single quote in it, which is prematurely causing one of your quoted strings in the query to end.

Without knowing what the exact error is, I can't be sure though. You should be checking for errors with something like `mysql_error()`. If you use that and show your error message, I'll be able to help you more.

Tossing data directly from user input (which is what `$_POST` contains) is a Very Bad Idea. You're better off using PDO and prepared statements.

Rather than writing a whole rant on this again, I'll just direct you to an answer I wrote the other day. You can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127218/mysql-select-where-value-rowitem/7127435#7127435).

Answer (score 0):

Create a **new field** (ex: `Id`) in your table `persons` and set it to `auto_increment`.